# Load related products inside description file

Tags: product, related-products

I want to load the related products inside the `/catalog/product/view/description.phtml` file.

Therefore I added the following code, but the related products are not loaded.

What am I missing?

CODE:

```
<section id="accessoires">
    <div class="product-accessoires">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php if (isset($section['related'])) {?>
                <?php echo $section['related']; ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```